# How do I disable mount on AIX?

Tags: filesystems, aix

I want to disable mount mentioned in /etc/filesystems. (By disabling I mean set the *mount* option to *false*).

I heard, that the */etc/filesystems* file, should not be edited directly, so I don't want to edit it using vim or other editor.

Is there any command I could use for this ? (I found that command *chnfsmnt* might help me with that, but I am not sure how to construct it to change the *mount* parameter to *false*).

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I solved this using *smitty* tool. (Specifically *smitty nfs*, as I wanted to remove NFS filesystem).

Alternatively, you can use the underlying [`chnfsmount`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-chnfsmnt-command) command with the `-a` option, which:

> specifies that it should not be automatically mounted at system restart

`smitty nfs` - "Change / Show Attributes of an NFS File System" uses `chnfsmount` under the covers to execute the changes from smitty. To use it, you have to specify the remote NFS mount with three options:

- -f PathName
- -d RemoteDirectory
- -h RemoteHost

... followed by the change you want.

To disable the mounting of remote-host:/remote-directory to /local-mount-point, you would run:

```bsh
chnfsmnt -f /local-mount-point -d /remote-directory -h remote-host -a
```

... which is the same as editing /etc/filesystems to change the "mount" flag to "false" for that filesystem.

Comment: Smitty is a wrapper but you can display command(s) it executes. It would be nice if you could post them here as part of answer.

Comment: @MariuszZieliński I've added the underlying command (example) as an update. It's not an exact mirror of a `smitty nfs` ... sequence, since the smitty screen captures all of the arguments, even the ones that aren't changing, but it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration.